# undefined variable: dbh Not sure what to do

Tags: apache, server, web, web-hosting

Ive recently been trying to re-setup a website i made a while ago. It is now hosted on a raspberry pi. When trying to enter values into the sql table i get an error.

> could not find driver
>   Notice: Undefined variable: dbh in /var/www/html/memes/inc/php/pdo_connect.php on line 32
>   Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in /var/www/html/memes/inc/php/pdo_connect.php:32 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/memes/inc/php/register.php(10): dataQuery('INSERT INTO `us...', Array) #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/memes/inc/php/pdo_connect.php on line 32

This is the pdo_connect code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

define('USER', ****');
define('PASS', '****');

function dataQuery($query, $params) {
    // what kind of query is this?
    $queryType = explode(' ', $query);

    // establish database connection
    try {
        $dbh = new 
PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=users', 
USER, PASS);
        $dbh-
>setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, 
false);
        $dbh-
>setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, 
PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        $errorCode = $e->getCode();
    }

    // run query
    try {
        $queryResults = $dbh-
>prepare($query);
        $queryResults->execute($params);
        if($queryResults != null && 'SELECT' == $queryType[0]) {
            $results = $queryResults-
>fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $results;
        } else {
            return $queryResults->rowCount();
        }
        $queryResults = null; // first of the two steps to properly close
        $dbh = null; // second step tp close the connection
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    $errorMsg = $e->getMessage();
    echo '<div align="center"><font color="red">too slow, username already taken</font></div>';
    //echo $errorMsg;
    }
}

?>
```

thanks for any help

Comment: this is the register code:                                        
 <?php
include 'pdo_connect.php';

if(!empty($_POST)) {
    $uname = $_POST['uname'];
    $upassword = password_hash($_POST['upassword'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $query = 'INSERT INTO `users` ( `uname`, `upassword`) VALUES (?,?)'; //if duplicate exists returns a duplicate error.
 
    $params = array($uname, $upassword);
    $results = dataQuery($query, $params);
 
 

}

?>

Comment: The website address is spicymemes.ddns.net if you want to try yourself